# Chromatic aberration in human eye

Tags: optics, biophysics, vision

A lens focuses the different colours of white light at different points. Since our eye has a convex lens there should also be such an aberration but we see objects clearly with normal eye. I want to know how eye is able to correct this aberration?

Comment: your eyes use your brain

Comment: Duplicate of  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12602/

Comment: You may already know this... http://www.theguardian.com/education/2012/nov/12/improbable-research-seeing-upside-down.....your brain does the interpretive work related to sight.