# Effects of chromatic aberration in the human eye

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, biophysics, vision

Due to metamerism, many different light spectra can be used to show a white colour.
If I understand it correctly, it is even possible to make white light by combining only two monochromatic light sources, for example 440 nm and 570 nm.
Displays often have three primaries (red, green and blue), and if these are monochromatic (e.g. BT.2020 colour space), there is a large gap in the spectrum between the red and green light components.
Since the spectral sensitivities of L and M cones overlap and the sensitivites of the S cones are further away, I assume that mostly the L and M cones contribute to sharpness perception with a greyscale image.

If a greyscale image is displayed with monochromatic blue and 570 nm light instead of light from a mix of three monochromatic primaries, does the image look sharper because there is less chromatic aberration affecting the L and M cones?
Or is it more difficult to focus on the image because there are less chromatic cues?

Is the difference between chromatic aberration with sun light and chromatic aberration with artificial light (e.g. from a display) related to emmetropization problems (myopia or hyperopia)?
And if so, does a Low Blue Light display foster or inhibit the development of emmetropization problems in comparison to a display which has low-frequency blue light?

Somewhat related question: [Do eyeballs exhibit chromatic aberration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12602/do-eyeballs-exhibit-chromatic-aberration)

Comment: useful article when discussing color perception http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html